# reading data from Json file format and using it without localstorage

Tags: jquery, json, each, getjson

I have been trying to read data from a Json source and i am getting the data in the browsers console as follows :

```
 Object {Tweets: Array[10]}
 Tweets: Array[10]
 0: Object
 1: Object
 2: Object
 3: Object
 4: Object
 5: Object
 6: Object
 7: Object
 8: Object
 9: Object
```

in Addition each Object has more data:

```
  0: {_id: {$oid: "554d57f7e97e6699f5244d9d"}, TWITTER_ID: 2911695560, USER_ID: "55406d3ee97e79138156d553",…}
  1: {_id: {$oid: "554d57f7e97e6699f5244d9e"}, TWITTER_ID: 2911695560, USER_ID: "55406d3ee97e79138156d553",…}
```

and i am trying to access them through my Jquery code .Is there a way to loop through them all.Here is how i am trying to access each objects data

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var gettodaystaskdb = "http://enla.com/Livee/rt/sus";

     $.getJSON(gettodaystaskdb, function (todaytask) {

         $(todaytask).each(function (index, element) {
             console.log(todaytask);
             console.log(index);
             console.log(element);

             var p = element.TWEET_ID;
             var q = element.TWEET;
             var r = element.TWEET_TIME;

             console.log(p);
         });

     });
 });
```

element.key doesn't seem to work and all i get is  *"Undefined"* .Is there a way that could possibly help me show the whole raw data .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looped the wrong part. This maybe a correction:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var gettodaystaskdb = "http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census";

  $.getJSON(gettodaystaskdb, function (todaytask) {
    console.log(todaytask);

    $.each(todaytask["Tweets"], function (index, element) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(element);

      var p = element.TWEET_ID;
      var q = element.TWEET;
      var r = element.TWEET_TIME;

      console.log(p);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it doesn't show the right data for var r  though .Do i need to declare it as an array variable? Thanks in Advance

Comment: `TWEET_TIME` is an object. You need to `element.TWEET_TIME['$date']` to get the date in string.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your function. Check the following code,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var gettodaystaskdb = "http://enlytica.com/RSLivee/rest/census";
  $.getJSON(gettodaystaskdb, function(todaytask) {
    $(todaytask.Tweets).each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(todaytask);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(element);

     var p= element.TWEET_ID;
     var q= element.TWEET;
     var r= element.TWEET_TIME;

     console.log(p);
     console.log(q);
     console.log(r);

    });
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it doesn't show the right data for var r though .Do i need to declare it as an array variable? Thanks in Advance